# A shortcut that works on all OS's on all Browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

For my javascript app on https://teletext.io we need a shortcut to launch the editor. The idea is to include a javascript on your own website and pressing a key combination like ALT+SHIFT+T will enable editing mode. However a combination like that doesn't work in all browsers (on all OS's).

For example:

```
function addKeyboardShortcut() {
  window.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (keyid === 84 && event.altKey && event.shiftKey) {
      txt.loadAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

How to pick a shortcut that does not interfere with the default browser shortcuts, what is the safest option?

Edit: simplified code as Alexey pointed out.

Comment: I don't know about best shortcut, but your code is overcomplicated. You just need to listen `keyup` and check `event.altKey` and `event.shiftKey` flags. No need to explicitely process them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Properties